# Using LINQ/Lambda to validate data before continuing

Tags: c#, linq, validation, lambda, observablecollection

I have a WPF MVVM project. I enter some data into a View and it must populate a gridview.

Now when I enter the data, I want to check that a certain value has not been entered already.
Basically, if student Mike has his name on the list already, an error comes up and asks you to change the name.

So far I have an observablecollection that gets populated with every button click.

```
studentList.Add(new Students()
{
    Name=Name,
    Age=Age,
    Class=Class
});

OnPropertyChanged(null);
```

where Name, Age and Class are the fields in the table/list and the same names used for the Textblocks. And OnPropertyChanged is a method I use to refresh the gridview.
Now how do I check if the same Name has been entered already?

I tried:

```
var duplicates = studentList.Where(x => x.Name== Name);
     if (!duplicates.Equals(Name))
     {
          //add data to gridview
     }
     else
        //showerror
```

but it didn't work for me. 
Where did I go wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
if(!studentList.Any(x => x.Name == Name)
{
    //add data to gridview
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(studentList.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Where(x=>x.Count()>2)
{
    // show error
}
else
{
    // add data to gridview
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any method is helpful here

```
if(!studentList.Any(x => x.Name == Name)
{
    //add data to gridview
}
else
{
// some error
}
```